# push particular folder and file only to repository from local master

Tags: git, gitignore

i am doing an angular 6 Project. In git i don't want to push the node modules folder to the repository. 
Except one folder i want push entire folder and files is it possible or i have to do other way?? 
in my folder

1. e2e/..
2. node_modules/...
3. src/...
4. editorconfig
5. gitignore
6. angular.json
7. package.json
8. README.md
9. tsconfig.json
10. tslint.json

i don't want the node-modules in to remote repository so there is any command to push the entire folder except sub folder node-modules

Comment: I have edited your tags as they have nothing to do with Angular or Node. Why don't you simply add `/node_modules` to .gitignore ?

Comment: In `.gitignore`, add `node_modules/` and save it.

Answer (score 0):

you can add specific file or folder

- `git add <file or folder path>`
- `git commit - "<commit message>"`
- `git push`

**Example:**
Here i need to add `.gitignore` file only
`git status`

new file:   test/test.html
new file:   .gitignore

`git add .gitignore`
`git commit -m "add gitignore"`
`git push`

if any queries comment below